# How can I get a query result in perl?

Tags: sql, perl

I tried this script to obtain some info from DB:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh;
my $query= "SELECT table_name FROM user_tables";
my $queryH;
my @tables_names;
my $i;
my $db_pass2 = "*****";
my $db_user2 = "*****"; 

print "DB connection...\n\n";

#DB connection
$dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:Oracle:host=***********;sid=*****;port=***', $db_user2, $db_pass2);
$queryH = $dbh->prepare($query);

print " ".$queryH->execute()."\n";

print "\n\n";

$queryH->finish();

$dbh->disconnect();

print "\n\n End!!!\n";
```

Why `$queryH->execute()` return me 0E0? How can I get a string as result?
I need to get the table name from the db... How can I get it with this script?

Answer (score 3):

`execute` only executes the query. To retrieve the results you have to use one of the many retrieval methods documented under [Statement Handle Methods](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Statement-Handle-Methods). For example:

```
$queryH->execute;
my ( $table_name ) = $queryH->fetchrow_array;
print "result = $table_name\n";
```